# sorting a dictionary by mean of their values

Tags: python, csv, sorting, dictionary

I've been trying to create a function that sorts a CSV file by mean of their values then write the output to another CSV file. The problem is I just don't know how to sort the dictionary by mean of their values.

Here's the input:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
jach,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sarah,0,5,20,14
julie,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ally,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

The expected output:

```
ally,5.0
jach,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
julie,7.833333333333333
sarah,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

And Here's the code:

```py
def calculate_sorted_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open (input_file_name) as f:
        a = []
        file1 = csv.reader(f)
        file2 = OrderedDict()
        for element in list(file1):
            file2[element[0]] = [int(j) for j in element[1:]]
        for i in file2:
            a.append((i + ',' + str(mean(file2[i]))))
    with open (output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as o:
        file3 = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\n')
        file3.writerow(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to read the data, convert the numbers to integers, calculate the mean, sort it and write back to file:

```
data = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        name, *vals = line.split(',')
        data.append([name, sum(map(int, vals)) / len(vals)])

data = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k[1])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in data:
        print(','.join(map(str, line)), file=f_out)
```

Creates `output.txt`:

```
ally,5.0
jach,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
julie,7.833333333333333
sarah,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```